# Periodic magnetic potential in quantum Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, crystals, magnetic-moment

In the Born-Oppenheimer approximation and considering independent spinless electrons, with the following Schrödinger Hamiltonian of a crystal, 
$$\hat{H} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(-i\vec{\nabla} + \vec{A}\right)^2 + V, $$
where $\vec{A},V$ are periodic, what does the periodic magnetic potential $\vec{A}$ model?

By Stokes formula, the magnetic flux per unit cell is zero, so it can't be ferromagnetism.

A friend suggested that it could be antiferromagnetism, where we don't want to include the spin in the model, but still want to retain the mean-field effects of local magnetic moments from valence electrons on conduction electrons.

Does this make sense? Any references to read up on this? 
(Math student here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a general answer, but one thing your Hamiltonian might model is a system in an external magnetic field. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.10046) is an example where the vector potential, see their Eq. (2), is

$$\vec{A} = \frac{B}{K} (-\sin(Ky),\sin(Kx),0).$$

They discuss in the introduction that such a field may be generated by external periodic structures, such as strips or dots of magnets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't understand though. In what you propose, $\vec{A}$ is not periodic, only $\vec{B}$ is.

Comment: Of course, you're completely right, sorry about that. I have edited the answer to actually answer your question.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question, not at all what I expected, but very interesting paper!

Comment: I'm curious, what were you expecting? I do condensed matter physics, and I almost always use your kind of Hamiltonian to describe external fields. It sounds a bit like you were expecting it to describe the microscopic order of a material? But in the Hamiltonian of e.g. a ferromagnet, usually no explicit magnetic fields enter, rather they appear due to spin interactions. See e.g. the [Heisenberg model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)).

Comment: Yes, that is indeed very reasonable. Well, the rationale for what my friend suggested is that including spin in computations like DFT, Hartree-Fock, is quite hard, and maybe a full description of spin for core and valence electrons is overkill if we are interested in the properties of conduction electrons. Hence, it might be enough to simulate only conduction electrons with spin, and introduce a mean-field approximation of the magnetic moments of valence electrons through a periodic magnetic vector potential.

Comment: In an antiferromagnetic material, it seems we could have non-trivial magnetic moments in each unit cell, but the magnetic flux per unit cell would still be $0$. We both now very little about magnetism, so this was just a wild guess. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Hm, I am no expert on the details of the numerics you mention, but it sounds reasonable to simulate only conduction electron spins in a background of the valence electrons and ions. But this is basically the same as modelling the conduction electrons as free electrons in an external magnetic field generate by the rest of the system, right? So I guess the two ideas match.

Comment: Sure! My surprise was the relation to Moiré patterns and flat bands. I didn’t think about the periodicity of the magnetic potentials being a superlattice symmetry, but it makes a lot of sense!